# Powershell : Trying to identify AD accounts without a specific permission group

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list all accounts in our users OU, that don't have a certain account in their security tab. We have set this account to inherit from the parent, but some accounts don't seem to working properly.

I have tried the following, but it just shows the users that have the account, not the ones that don't. I have tried the -ne variable, but it just seems to remove the account from the list.

Get-QADUser -SearchRoot 'domain/Accounts/Users/Corporate' -SecurityMask Dacl | Get-QADPermission -SchemaDefault -Inherited | Where-Object {$_.AccountName -eq 'domain\Prod_Svc_RLoader'
}

I just need the account list, not the permissions list also.

I know I have missed something obvious, just cant figure out what !

Cheers,
Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Where-Object earlier in the pipeline. Try something like this:

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot 'domain/Accounts/Users/Corporate' -SecurityMask Dacl | Where-Object -FilterScript { -not (Get-QADPermission $_ -SchemaDefault -Inherited | Where-Object {$_.AccountName -eq 'domain\Prod_Svc_RLoader' }) }
```

I'm not familiar with the Quest AD cmdlets, but hopefully you see what we're trying to do here. Basically, we're "-not'ting" the users who **do** have the ACE for `Prod_Svc_RLoader` in their DACL.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Running the search now. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, that command now works and identifies the account(s) without the ACE. Many thanks :)